# Does Laravel support scaffolding?

Tags: php, yii2, laravel-5, scaffolding

Yii framework has a very good module that provides scaffolding (generates CRUD with forms - responsive) known as `GII`. It generates the basic search grid, insert, update and delete for a database entity. It really speeds up the develop.

I am planning to develop another product in Laravel, I didn't come across any scaffolding tutorial.

Do we have any scaffolding module in Laravel 5.X ?

Comment: yes it does: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

Comment: Not sure if as effective as GII though. I also use Yii as my preferred framework.

Comment: do we have for laravel 5? is this from the community?

Comment: see my answer OP. Provided link for both laravel 4 and 5. :)

Comment: yes checked it, but not as good as GII..check it out there.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B52-li6IgU

Comment: hmm.. gii is the best nevertheless :)

Answer (score 2):

Try The [Scaffold-Interface](https://github.com/amranidev/scaffold-interface)
generate your model,view,controller + one to many relationship just in few clicks.

Answer (score 1):

You can used Ping pong module generator this is really helpfull for me.

http://sky.pingpong-labs.com/docs/2.1/modules

just try it i hope this is helpfull for you.

it's generate full module like yii2 generator Grid,insert,update,delete,etc.....

Comment: checked it but not as good as gii ..check it out there.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B52-li6IgU

Answer (score 0):

Yes It does. They have Generators for the same purpose. As for example, [Laravel 4 Generator](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) in github should do it for you. Not sure if as effective as Gii though. You should do some experiment on this.

Edit: [Laravel 5 Generator](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) in github.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is so flexible .. Lots of packages out there especially for laravel . surely you could get a decent package .. You could refer this FYI [laravel package for curd](https://github.com/mitulgolakiya/laravel-api-generator)